# Поиск в строке с символами кириллицы

Tags: perl

Есть файл в кодировке utf-8 со строками с кириллицей. Как сделать независимый от регистра поиск? Как ищу(накидал тестовый скрипт):

```
use CGI; 
use utf8;

print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";

$query = new CGI; 

if ($query->param("search") ne "") { &my_search($query->param("search")); }
---

sub my_search {
  my($search_for) = @_;

  $search_for =~ tr/ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮЁ/
  йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюё/;

  my(@list_search);

  open(DB,"<db.dat");
  while (<DB>) {
    my @str =  split(/\|/, $_); 
    @str[3] =~ tr/ЙЦУКЕНГШЩЗХЪФЫВАПРОЛДЖЭЯЧСМИТЬБЮЁ/
    йцукенгшщзхъфывапролджэячсмитьбюё/;

    if (@str[3] =~ m/$search_for/ig) { push @list_search, @str[3]; }
  }
  close(DB);

  foreach $element(@list_search) {
    $html .= "$search_for = $element<br>"; 
  }

  print <<HTML;

  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ru">

  $html 

  HTML
  exit;
}
```

Вместо `use locale;` пробовал всё, что предлагает Гугл и здесь находил, например:

```
use open qw(:utf8);
binmode(STDIN,':utf8');
binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');
```

Ничего не помогает! Функция uc() тоже не работает! `Паровоз -> Паровоз` находит,
`паровоз -> Паровоз` - нет!

Answer (score 0):

Вот так заработало:

```
use Encode;
$search_for = encode_utf8(lc(decode_utf8($search_for)));
```

Без всяких use locale и т.п. Всем спасибо!

Comment: Для выделения кода на панели инструментов есть специальный инструмент обозначенный фигурными скобками `{}`.